# Updating column values of Oracle 11g HR schema

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to update the salaries of all employees to the maximum salary of the department in which s/he works.

ERD: 
[image]

My try:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET
(SELECT SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY SALARY, DEPARTMENT_ID) = 
(SELECT "MAX"(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID);
```

Obviously this is wrong. It gives the error:

`ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification`

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
    SET SALARY = (SELECT MAX(SALARY)
                  FROM EMPLOYEES E2
                  WHERE E2.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `merge`

```
   MERGE INTO EMPLOYEES a
    USING ( SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, MAX(SALARY) as sal
                      FROM EMPLOYEES group by DEPARTMENT_ID
         ) b
    ON ( a.DEPARTMENT_ID = b.DEPARTMENT_ID )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET  a.SALARY = b.sal
```